# What do teammates shout on BO2 Multiplayer?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

In **multi-player**, the character you're playing as and your teammates sometimes say some things like "Changing Mag", "Grenade..! Grenade..!" , "Sniper's down, move up", etc.

Does anybody know what they say here?

Here's an example at 5s:

And also in the very beginnig of this one:

- Subboy (Support?)
- Confirmed.
- Going explosive get MSD (minimal security distance).
- Sniper's down, move up.
- Move it/Sniper..

Comment: If you tell us what mission and a more precise moment when it occurs, then your chances with getting help might be higher.

Comment: it's in multiplayer mode..

Comment: "Its a bomb" Maybe? With a racist accent you can only find in CoD games?

Comment: hmm maybe.. i'm trying to find it in a youtube video, i'll post the exact moment here

Comment: @FullMetalAlcheBlitz please check out the video I just posted

Comment: @DrFish please check out the video I just posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The player and other players deliberately shout these comments as if they were talking through a Communication device to their teammates for added realism.

Here are the reasons for all your "shouts":

- **Support!** (Subboy) is said when throwing down Tactical Equipment (which is obviously to *support* your team)
- **Going Explosive!** is said again, obviously when throwing explosives towards enemies, asking teammates to back away, keeping them safe.
- **Snipers down, move up!** is said when you/team kills an enemy sniper, basically meaning "You are free to poke your head out now!"
- **Move it! Sniper!** is said when an enemy sniper starts shooting or kills a teammate indicating that you need to get down and be ready for it.
- **Confirmed!** I don't really know this one well, but I'm 99% sure it's when you confirm a dog tag, or instead, kill an enemy, *confirming a kill*.

If there's anymore you want me to "transcribe" then just give me a shout.
Good luck!

Comment: So "subboy" is a slang for "support" ?

Comment: @MajidL No. xD I just put it there so you know that Support is what it actually was. I'm not saying your wrong (it actually sounds like Subboy) I just put it there so you personally don't get confused. Want me to remove it?

Comment: actually it's the only one that I couldn't understand.. because it doesn't sound much like "support" to me.. I don't have a problem with the others :)

Comment: @MajidL That's fine. I understand. It's the same with songs, sometimes they sound like their saying something completely different. Question: Does this answer your question?

Comment: @MajidL No problem! Thanks. If you have any other questions, feel free to reply to this.

Answer (score 2):

To me with my headphones on it sounds like he is saying "Support".

Comment: I don't think so.. :-/ Check the other video I just found

Comment: 100% support. If I throw down any tactical equipment it shouts support.

Comment: well i can't argue with native english speakers but i will leave the question open for a while.. if there's no other answer then the bounty is yours :)

Comment: This isn't an answer Butter. It's an addon. You could of posted this as a comment.

Comment: I did post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, but you could of commented it saying "It sounds like support to me!"